# Using break in Python if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, break

I am having a beginner mistake and i can't see where I have gone wrong.

I am trying to break the program if commandline argument[0] is empty.

I'm running python on macports.

```
import sys

script = sys.argv[0]
ip = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]

if script is None:
    print 'script argv is: ' + script
    break

print "[+] The script name is: " + script
print "[+] The IP is: " +IP+" and the port is: " +port
```

I keep getting this error.

```
mars13:python beebs$ python sys.py
  File "sys.py", line 9
    break
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Line 9 refers to break.

Comment: The error is telling you are trying to use a `break` statement when there is no loop your `if` statement is not a loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break` can only be used in a `while` or `for` loop; you are trying to use in in an `if` statement instead.

To exit your script early, use the [`sys.exit()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Note that `sys.argv[0]` is always going to be a string (in some circumstances it can be an *empty* string), so `if script is None` is *always* going to be false. For your script it'll be set to `'sys.py'`.

You should not give your script the same name as a Python standard library module; you named yours `sys.py`, and only because the module is a built-in and doesn't require loading from a separate file do you get away with that, so in *this specific case* you were lucky and didn't cause any problems with importing. However, in the general case you'd end up with an import error as your script would be imported instead.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! It worked! Now i am getting stuck at ip = sys.argv[1] with error message of IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: @PooT: yes, `sys.argv` is just a list, and if you don't give command line arguments you'll have a shorter list (at minimum it'll be 1 element long).

Comment: @PooT: so you'd check for the length: `if len(sys.argv) <= 1:` would be true if there is just the script name in the list.